# JUnit Test method with HttpSession object in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to test a method that accepts a session object as a parameter and returns boolean according to certain conditions.

My question is: How can I pass a **non-null session object** to my method in JUnit test (using spring boot)?

I have tried several methods but I keep getting *java.lang.NullPointerException* errors.

Comment: Have a look at `org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession` (in spring-test).

Comment: @teppic have used many variations of `MockHttpSession` keeps giving me `NullPointerException` errors. For example:
`MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession(webApplicationContext.getServletContext());`

Comment: Add a minimal example to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a victim of [slf4j - IllegalAccessError](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#IllegalAccessError) errors, whenever I ran the test it kept giving me random errors but this was the most consistent. I had to debug the issue in my classpath, pom and found out that the culprit was library dependencies, an old version of slf4j was being used instead of the one I set in pom.xml.

After removing and rebuilding the module, the test errors cleared.

Thanks.